# What did Hisoka whisper to Bodoro?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In episode 20 during the Hunter Examination, after knocking down Bodoro, Hisoka whispered something to Bodoro and conceded after. I don't know if it has shown what Hisoka said or whispered that i might've miss or it never did showed it in the anime.

So what exactly did Hisoka whisper to Bodoro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one really knows, as it has never been revealed.

But a common theory is that Hisoka whispered something to him along the lines of "If you don't forfeit, I am going to fight the children", as Bodoro doesn't like to fight or harm children. You can read up more about him and form your own theory [here](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Bodoro).